Cannot use jsx with Rollup
I'm using Rollup to compile my tsx files to js files. I have the following config:
// @ts-check
import multiInput from "rollup-plugin-multi-input";
import typeScript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";

export default [
  {
    input: "packages/**/!(etech-ui-utils|etech-ui-dev)/**/*.tsx",
    output: {
      format: "esm",
      dir: ".registry/esm"
    },
    plugins: [multiInput(), typeScript()]
  },
  {
    input: "packages/**/!(etech-ui-utils|etech-ui-dev)/**/*.ts",
    output: {
      format: "cjs",
      dir: ".registry/cjs"
    },
    plugins: [multiInput(), typeScript()]
  },
  {
    input: "packages/etech-ui-utils/src/index.ts",
    output: {
      format: "esm",
      dir: "dist/packages/etech-ui-utils/esm"
    },
    plugins: [typeScript()]
  },
  {
    input: "packages/etech-ui-utils/src/index.ts",
    output: {
      format: "cjs",
      dir: "dist/packages/etech-ui-utils/cjs"
    },
    plugins: [typeScript()]
  }
];


My tsconfig.react.json:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "strict": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "bundler",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "jsx": "react-jsx",
      "incremental": true,
      "composite": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "paths": {
        "@/*": ["./*"]
      }
    },
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "include": ["**/*.tsx", "**/*.jsx", "**/*.stories.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "references": [
      {
        "path": "./tsconfig.storybook.json"
      }
    ]
  }

When running the rollup -cw command I get an error:
[!] (plugin rpt2) RollupError: [plugin rpt2] packages/example/stories/Example.stories.tsx:2:21 - error TS6142: Module '../Example' was resolved to '/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/packages/example/Example.tsx', but '--jsx' is not set.

I have tried using the workspace version of TypeScript in vscode. I have also tried restarting vscode.
Additionally I tried the "jsx": "preserve" and "jsx": "react-jsx". I cannot use react because I want the components to compile to standard jsx.
